# Article presenting first evidence for dark matter?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, dark-matter, galaxies, specific-reference

What are the papers where the first evidence for dark matter related with the stability of galactic discs, and the orbits of galaxy satellites?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/84967).

Comment: The problem is this, my professor said to include these in my paper. Nevertheless every search I've done about it comes up empty.  Google, Google scholar, arxiv.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform is right you know. Have you tried reading the wiki Dark Matter entry and specifically the section History? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Early_history

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/406057/how-did-we-discover-dark-matter

Comment: @JDOe Try asking on [HSM.SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/). Perhaps there your question won't be voted as off-topic.

Comment: Yes I have, but there is very little about this particular topic

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open because [tag:specific-references] are on-topic.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform & others: the title makes this sound trivial (everyone cites Zwicky '33), but the specifics in the question make it a bit more subtle. None of the references I dug up (well, except Zwicky, which you could take as being about 'satellites') are mentioned on the Wikipedia page cited above as support for closing this for insufficient prior research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll have a go. Keep in mind that at the time of the references given below, "dark matter" wasn't yet commonly thought of as some unknown weakly interacting particle, it was just "gravitating stuff we can't see", it was common at the time to assume that it might be gas in some phase that wasn't easily observed (no strong emission/absorption signal). Actually we still think there's a bunch of unseen gas out there, but not enough to account for the "needed" amount of dark matter. Anyway, before I get off on too big a tangent...

For disk stability, I'm fairly confident that I've found the original reference in [Ostriker & Peebles (1973)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/#abs/1973ApJ...186..467O/abstract). They also cite [Kalnajs (1972)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/#abs/1972ApJ...175...63K/abstract), who notes "The fixed background field provided by the halo has a stabilizing effect on the disk [...]", but this is in a more theoretical context of an orbital stability study, whereas Ostriker & Peebles directly make the connection to the then- (and still) hot topic of the missing mass problem in real-world systems. Given that you asked for "evidence", this seems to better fit the bill.

For satellite motion, it depends if you count [Zwicky (1933)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/#abs/1933AcHPh...6..110Z/abstract), which deals with the velocity dispersion of galaxies in clusters, which is much higher than expected from an estimate of the mass of those galaxies. This is usually cited as the first argument for dark matter. If galaxies in a cluster satisfy your definition of 'satellites', then this may be what you're after. Otherwise I propose [Einasto et al. (1974)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/#abs/1974Natur.250..309E/abstract). They use interacting pairs of galaxies (I'd call one of these a 'satellite') to infer the mass in galactic systems out to large radii, and note a large amount of unseen mass.

Notes on accessibility of the articles: the Einasto paper is from Nature and is old, which for me made it a bit of a pain to access, I only got it by trying my accounts at libraries at several universities (or you can pay...). I think the others are easier, from what I can see it looks like ADS provides them open to anyone (but am on a university network, so I can't easily confirm this). The Zwicky article is in German. There is another [Einasto et al.](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/#abs/1974Natur.252..111E/abstract) paper in the same year which may also be of interest (also Nature, also a pain to access), it has to do with the morphological segregation of satellites of the Milky Way, which they propose to attribute to a massive unseen halo (of gas, however).

If you're curious to know how I located these, my starting point was citations in the section on disk stability in Binney & Tremaine's "Galactic Dynamics" textbook, and for the satellites citations in the section outlining the rise of the CDM paradigm in "Galaxy formation and evolution" by Mo, van den Bosch & White. From there I read the articles I cite, and did a bit of legwork on [ADS](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/#), to check for earlier work.