# Does dark matter interact with baryonic matter only through the gravitational field?

Tags: gravity, astrophysics, dark-matter, interactions, galaxy-rotation-curve

Do I understand correctly that dark matter fields are interact with baryonic matter only through the gravitational field? In this case, how can it be registred at all if it does not interact with the electromagnetic field in any way? Or is there interaction, only it is very weak?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_rotation_curve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How did we 'discover' dark matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/406057/)

Comment: Is it possible for the existence of absolutely non-interacting quantum fields?

Comment: That’s an unrelated question. Dark matter interacts gravitationally with ordinary matter.

Comment: The question is related. If the existence of absolutely non-interacting quantum fields is impossible, then dark matter should interact with ordinary matter, albeit very weakly.